# Is it possible to stretch font in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox

Is to possible to stretch Font in WinForms? What I am trying to accomplish is to stretch font to maximum available RichTextBox width. It should be something like viewbox in WPF. 
My goal is to stretch font NOT TO resize it. All fonts I am using are mono spaced fonts.

Comment: AFAIK it's **not possible**. What you can do is to **mimic** (more or less) what **WPF** does: **draw your rtb into a bitmap** then draw that bitmap stretched.

Comment: Graphics.ScaleTransform + Graphics.DrawString.  But that's a big no on RichTextBox, as with other controls that are actually implemented by Windows, they do their own text rendering.

Answer (score 3):

yes  it's possible  to do this

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics gr = richTextBox1.CreateGraphics();
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        float x = 0.0F;
        float y = 0.0F;
        float width = 200.0F;
        float height = 50.0F;
        Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 18);

        RectangleF drawRect = new RectangleF(x, y, width, height);
         //here you  can shrink  as you want 
        gr.ScaleTransform(3, 1);
        gr.DrawString("your text", drawFont, brush, drawRect);

    }
```

Hope this help

Comment: Sorry it creates just a bitmap of RichTextBox content. I know about this solution, but using this you are loosing possibility to work with text for ex. selecting it or searching. I am looking for something like viewbox in WPF. Maybe third party component for WinForms.

Comment: This was the solution that I needed. I used ScaleTransform(1, 3) to scale the height of my font. Also to note, after using scale and reseting it, I had to do some more calculations to get the new and right Y position.